# Generating unique int Id for my Java classes used as cache keys

Tags: java

Can somebody suggest any approach to generate a unique ID, preferably an integer, for Java classes? I need to have each of my Java classes have some kind of a unique ID which would be written via a serialization strategy to be used to get back the same class in a distributed setup.

Comment: Does each instance have its own unique id? Does the id need to be the same across multiple jvms?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID%28%29) class. It has [toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#toString%28%29) function. You could take the hash of that value.

Comment: I need a int to be generated .The generated number needs to remain same always for that particular class .Will using UUID ensure that everytime I would get the same UUID and its hash code .

Answer (score 0):

While not an integer, another way is to use SecureRandom:

```
new BigInteger(130, new SecureRandom()).toString(32)
```

returns a String that looks something like "61iook8njttgnmp06aku56gmtc"

Note that if at all possible it would be better to create a single SecureRandom and reuse it when generating your unique id.

**Edit**: sorry, can't comment yet but I see that you added a comment to the UUID answer - also an excellent way to solve the original problem you stated.  However, now you want a "unique key" for your object.  You really need to come up with a correct hashCode() method for your object.  You need to answer what separates one version of your object from the other - a string perhaps that you could call hashCode() on?

Comment: Thanks for your replies ..I don't need different hash codes for my object rather I need a unique Id for my class which should remain constant ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm mot sure you can get what you want.

It would be nice to have the entire thing be an automated part of the build process so it sort of "just happens".

It seems the only near constant information available from a Java class to represent a unique class is the full package and class name "canonical path".  But if someone renames it or changes the package you are screwed.

To get any shorter ID that is assigned once and persistent will require some sort of persistent registry database loaded at application startup and available to all applications that will be serializing the same classes. You then look up the actual runtime class from it and assign it to an internal registry.

It would be nice if in some manner a unique ID can be generated when a class without an assigned ID is first created, and an annotation or other field can be added to the source code for the classes in question.