# How do I create an automatically incrementing id within a method

Tags: java

I must replace the -1 with something that will evaluate to the appropriate integer value for the new shopper's ID number.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MethodHolder {

    private static int nextShopperID = 100;
    private static int nextProductID = 100;

    protected static Shopper generateShopper(){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = null;
        double balance = 0.0;
        int productLimit = 0;

        System.out.println("Please enter the shoppers name: ");
        name = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter the shoppers balance: ");
        balance = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the shoppers product limit: ");
        productLimit = scan.nextInt();


        // replace -1 with the appropriate increment expression
        return new Shopper(-1, name, balance, productLimit); 
    }
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Do you know what an `if` statement is? Btw: [Generating unique int Id for my Java classes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32639692)

Comment: What is that `nextShopperID` intended to be? Could that be related to your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing in nextShopperID and increment it.

```
return new Shopper(nextShopperID++, name, balance, productLimit);
```